# How to get an HTML element by his href using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, href

I'm building an webview application which has unwanted html sections/blocks/buttons for my android app.

I want to remove them by overriding onPageFinished(). I've succeeded doing it for some elements.

On the webpage i have this element:

```
<footer>
    ...
    <a href="http://www.randomlink.com" style=""></a>
    ...
  </footer>
```

My java code:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {        
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('a')[98].style.display=\"none\";");
   }
```

It does work with 98... but I don't want magic numbers, i want to be able to catch it by his href so it works in any page.

[edit] Forgot to say that I'm working with a 3rd party webpage - leaving me no choice but to block unwanted implementations on my webview application.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by it's attribute.

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var wantedElement = null;

for(var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++)
{
    if(aTags[i].getAttribute("href") == "www.example.com")
    {
        wantedElement = aTags[i];
        //break out of loop
    };
}
```

With jQuery:

```
var element = $('a[href$="Your href"]');
```

Comment: Won't that give me the href attribute? I want the element itself, searching it by his href

Comment: Yes, you would just need to do something like if(el.getAttribute("href") == "your href you're searching for"). It is much easier in jQuery but you didn't specify if you could use it in your project.

Comment: I can use any approach, I'm just not sure how to inject jQuery code on the webview, if it's similar to the way I'm doing with js - i would be glad to use it!

Comment: You just need a reference to jQuery either on your view page or the shared master page.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with a 3rd party webpage, leaving me no choice but to block via the client.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. You just need to loop over the DOM elements to find the one you are looking for by it's attribute.